# Building libobjc2 with CMake + Clang + MinGW on Linux

Tags: cmake, clang, cross-compiling, mingw-w64, libobjc2

I'm trying to cross compile [libobjc2](https://github.com/gnustep/libobjc2) from Arch to Windows. I use the following command to configure with CMake:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=x86_64 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=$CLANG_WINDOWS_XFLAGS -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=$CLANG_WINDOWS_XFLAGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/opt/cross/windows/gnustep
```

`CLANG_WINDOWS_XFLAGS` is defined as:

```
export CLANG_WINDOWS_XFLAGS="-target x86_64-w64-mingw32 -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/clang/3.6.0/include -isystem /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -isystem /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/5.1.0 -isystem /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/5.1.0/backward -isystem /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/5.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
```

After running `make`, the `libobjc.dll` product is successfully built, but it fails:

```
Linking C shared library libobjc.dll
[ 39%] Built target objc
Scanning dependencies of target objcxx
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/objcxx.dir/objcxx_eh.cc.obj
Linking C shared library libobjcxx.dll
CMakeFiles/objcxx.dir/objects.a(objcxx_eh.cc.obj):(.text+0x24c): undefined reference to `object_getClass'
CMakeFiles/objcxx.dir/objects.a(objcxx_eh.cc.obj):(.text+0x261): undefined reference to `objc_getClass'
CMakeFiles/objcxx.dir/objects.a(objcxx_eh.cc.obj):(.text+0x314): undefined reference to `objc_getClass'
CMakeFiles/objcxx.dir/objects.a(objcxx_eh.cc.obj):(.text+0x32c): undefined reference to `objc_getClass'
CMakeFiles/objcxx.dir/objects.a(objcxx_eh.cc.obj):(.text+0x3ac): undefined reference to `class_getSuperclass'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
CMakeFiles/objcxx.dir/build.make:87: recipe for target 'libobjcxx.dll' failed
make[2]: *** [libobjcxx.dll] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/objcxx.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/objcxx.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:146: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can't seem to get MinGW to link the `libobjcxx.dll` to `libobjc.dll`. The library compiles successfully when not cross-compiling.

Any tips on how to get this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured that I would need to add `-lobjc` to the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, but it never occured to me to add a linker search path for the library. Running the following before `make` solves my problem:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Windows -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=x86_64 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=$CLANG_WINDOWS_XFLAGS -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="$CLANG_WINDOWS_XFLAGS -L`pwd` -lobjc" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/cross/windows/gnustep
```